# julia select all but one element in array/matrix

Tags: arrays, select, julia

I would like to know if it is possible to select all but one element (by index) in a julia array.

For example in R language in order to not select a particular row in a matrix one would write:

```
a = matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
a
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

and then:

```
a[-2, ]
1 4 7
3 6 9
```

Now I would like to do the same thing in julia. I tried using logical operators, but I cant find a way to (un) select a particular index. Here is what I tried:

```
a = rand(3,3)
a[.!= 2, :]
ERROR: syntax "!=" is not a unary operator
```

or as in R:

```
a[-2, :]
```

and a few other options. What is working in julia is the following:

```
a[a .>= .5, :]
```

or

```
a[[2,3], :]
```

to select the sec and third row. Anyway I would really like to know how to select all but one of a particular element (row for example) in a julia array.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
A = rand(3,3)
B = A[1:end .!= 2,:]
```

`1:end` gets a complete list of row indices (you could also use `1:size(A,1)`) and then `.!=` (note the `.` indicating element-wise comparison) selects the indices not equal to 2.

If you wanted to select columns in this way you would use:

```
C = A[:, 1:end .!= 2]
```

Note that the `end` keyword automatically will equal the last index value of the row, column, or other dimension you are referencing.

**Note:** answer updated to reflect improvements (using `end` instead of `size()`) suggested by @Matt B in comments.

Comment: Nice answer! I ll wait a bit longer before I put the question to ansered just to see what else comes up. But your approach is really nice.

Comment: This makes my life so much easier. Now I can avoid writing ugly nested for loops.

Comment: Even more fun: you can use `end` expressions like this: `A[1:end .!= 2, :]`.  Semantically, it's exactly the same — the parser just handles figuring out the correct `size` call for you.

Comment: I guess that fine enough. Still this should be implemented in base i think.

Comment: @Vincent I think there is sometimes a tradeoff between conciseness of notation and simplicity of rules.  The R notation is kind of clever and nice in its own sort of way.  But it doesn't necessarily follow as logically from knowing a few set of basic rules about how to access and manipulate arrays.  I'm not saying one way is better or worse, and I"m not myself a Julia developer, but there are tradeoffs.

Comment: This has been discussed as a potential candidate for inclusion in base: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1032.  It's not too hard to implement, and it could be developed in a package first.  As far as I'm aware, nobody's taken the time to do so yet.

Comment: Nice to see you're back, @MichaelOhlrogge :)

Comment: Thanks @TasosPapastylianou.  I'd only at best call myself sort of back.  I probably won't be doing a ton of answering these days, though here and there from time to time.  Hope all is well with you and your dissertation!

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `Not` function, which constructs an inverted index:

```
A = rand(3,3)
A[Not(2), :]
A[:, Not(2)]
```

You can find the `Not` function in the `InvertedIndices.jl` package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I have been looking for this! Note that it can also be used for several indices that should be excluded, i.e. `Not([2,5,10])` excludes all those entries.