# Julia: select all except a few indices

Tags: julia

In a previous question, it was asked how: [julia select all but one element in array/matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661221/julia-select-all-but-one-element-in-array-matrix/37661427).

In my case, I would like to select all except a few elements (more than one).

I have folds of indices chosen by [SelectedKFold](http://mlbasejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crossval.html#StratifiedKfold) from the MLBase package. I would like to also select the complement of those indices.

Right now, I am doing the following which is ugly:

```
total = 1:100
ix = 1:10
complement_ix = [e for e in total if !(e in ix)]
```

In R, this would be the same as doing `X[-ix,]` and in numpy I believe I could do `X[~ix]`. Is there a simpler way to do this in Julia?

Comment: `complement_ix = setdiff(1:100,1:10)` is another way

Comment: `setdiff` is the way. If you're writing a cross_validate function then you can see that's also how its done in MLBase (https://github.com/JuliaStats/MLBase.jl/blob/master/src/crossval.jl#L173)

Comment: @MattB. @Alexander Morley `setdiff([1,1,2,2,1,2,3],[1,1]) == [2,3]`. Wouldn't it be plausible to have it `== [2,2,2,3]` ? Would also be applicable to some cases of indexing (and then the name might have to be changed. `exclude` ? just `diff` ? `subtract` ?).

Comment: (continued comment) Could define it with: `subtract(v,s) = eltype(v)[e for e in v if e ∉ Set(s)]`

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant to this situation.  But I think we should consolidate any new discussion over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405048/how-to-index-all-but-select-indices.

Comment: You seem to be more concerned about "ugliness" than the actual implementation here. If this is the case, it is not difficult to define your own operator (e.g. ¬) to do something like: `A[¬[2,3]]`, implemented via one of the solutions in the post linked by Matt

Comment: I did not notice this was a duplicate. Let us move the discussion there.