# Selecting all entries of a vector except for specific ones in Julia

Tags: vector, julia

Suppose that I have a vector, e.g.

```
c = [10, 12, 13, 11]
```

in Julia. I want to choose all entries except the second and the third. I can write for example:

```
c[1:end .∉ [[2 3]]]
```

This gives

```
[10, 11]
```

as desired.

However, in some formats, e.g. LaTeX, I cannot report my code using ∉ symbol. Is there a way to write the same code without using ∉ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [julia select all but one element in array/matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661221/julia-select-all-but-one-element-in-array-matrix) or [How to index all but select indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39405048/11747148)

Comment: You can use `.!in.` instead of `.∉` like this: `c[.!in.(1:end,([2,3],))]`

Answer (score 3):

If it helps in any way, you can write those symbols in LaTeX by changing the engine, to LuaLaTeX or XeTeX. As an example

```latex
% Engine LuaLaTeX
% you can set this in the "menu" button at the top left corner, this will enable unicode in LaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Package to change font
\usepackage{minted} % Formatting code in LaTeX

\setmonofont{Apl385.ttf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
% The command above will change LaTeX monospaced font by the one of your choice (the font has to support the characters you want to use). I'll use one APL specific font but it will work as fine

\begin{document}

Julia code below that you can style however you want.
\begin{minted}{jl}
c = [10, 12, 13, 11]
c[1:end .∉ [[2 3]]]
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

With this output:
[image: LuaLaTeX output]

You can change the font to look different than my example here

Answer (score 1):

Other options are:

```
julia> using InvertedIndices

julia> c[Not([2, 3])]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 11
```

and

```
deleteat!(copy(c), [2, 3])
```

and

```
julia> [v for (i, v) in enumerate(c) if !(i in [2, 3])]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely wanted to do it in one line, you could do this:

```
c[(!in).(eachindex(c), Ref((2, 3)))]
```

Explanation:

```
julia> in(1, [2, 3, 4])
false

julia> (!in)(1, [2, 3, 4])
true

julia> (!in).([1, 2], Ref([2, 3, 4]))
2-element BitVector:
 1
 0

julia> (!in).([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Ref([2, 3, 4]))
5-element BitVector:
 1
 0
 0
 0
 1

julia> collect(eachindex(c))
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> idx = (!in).(eachindex(c), Ref((2, 3)))
4-element BitVector:
 1
 0
 0
 1

julia> c[idx]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 11

julia> c[(!in).(eachindex(c), Ref((2, 3)))]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 11
```